# Getting error as "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large", when trying to plot 17 scatter plots in 5 x 5 matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am new to R and I am trying to plot 17 graphs in one go.

My code is as given below:

Datafile must be saved as "dataframe". This contains 65,536 records of 18 variables

```
dataframe<-read.csv("c:/datasets/AirFlightDelayData.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Setup the variables and dependent at first

```
variables<-dataframe[,1:ncol(dataframe)-1]
dependent<-dataframe[,ncol(dataframe)]
fileheader<-c(colnames(variables))
```

find the size of square matrix to be filled by plotting

```
if(is.integer(sqrt(ncol(variables)))) {rownum=sqrt(ncol(variables))}                     else
  + {rownum=floor(sqrt(ncol(variables)))+1}
```

set par() as per the calculated size

```
par(mfrow=c(rownum,rownum), cex.main=1)
```

Run the for-loop for all variables, and plot the dependent field for each variable

```
for (n in 1:ncol(variables)) {varx<-variables[,n]   
varxnum<-as.numeric(varx)
dependentnum<-as.numeric(dependent)
plot(varxnum, dependentnum, main="Scatterplot Example",
     xlab=fileheader[n], ylab="Dependent", pch=5)}
```

This code is getting error as

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Comment: Error like that often means the plotting window is too small. Either you messed up your margins or the figure you're trying to produce is "large". 5x5 matrix of scatterplots fits the bill. Without a self-contained reproducible example we're stuck. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+figure+margins+too+large

Comment: HI Roman, Yes I believe I have messed up the margins. Because I tried to plot simple one graph for testing your concern, but nothing is coming also no error is generating. Yesterday I was trying many things with the margin and layouts, that might be the cause. How to get back to default settings?

Comment: Assuming you're in RStudio, try clicking the broom icon (Clear all plots). If that doesn't work, just restart your R session (Alt + S + R).